# Subsetting a data frame leads to an unexpected behaviour

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R and don't know whether this question is stupid or not, but I have the following problem:
I have two data frames, both containing a timestamp column (`Posixct`). I want to subset the data as follows:
The new `df3` shall contain all columns from `df1`, conditioned on the occurrence of the value "21" in the "State" column in `df2`. If this occurs, all observation from `df1` from 2 hours before until 1 hour after the occurrence of State 21 in `df2` shall be in the new `df3`.

here are two samples of my original data frames.

`df2`:

```
    timestamp           PlantNo State
37 2016-03-14 08:53:25       1     2
38 2016-03-14 09:31:43       1     0
39 2016-03-14 09:34:43       1     0
40 2016-03-14 13:49:18       1     2
41 2016-03-14 14:17:42       1     0
42 2016-03-14 14:20:41       1     0
43 2016-03-17 01:54:07       1     2
44 2016-03-17 07:06:23       1     0
45 2016-03-17 07:09:23       1     0
46 2016-03-17 10:10:11       1    21
47 2016-03-17 10:46:29       1     2
```

`df1`:

```
       timestamp        PlantNo Error avws maxws minws avrot maxrot minrot avpwr
1  2016-03-05 00:00:00       1     0  6.7   9.3   4.3 25.15  30.96  21.37    93
2  2016-03-05 00:10:00       1     0  7.9  11.1   5.5 29.05  34.26  22.89   145
3  2016-03-05 00:20:00       1     0  7.8  10.5   4.6 28.83  33.17  23.34   142
4  2016-03-05 00:30:00       1     0  7.8  10.4   5.3 28.91  33.94  24.09   142
5  2016-03-05 00:40:00       1     0  7.9  10.1   5.4 28.36  32.89  23.03   134
6  2016-03-05 00:50:00       1     0  7.8   9.2   5.4 27.83  31.41  22.48   126
7  2016-03-05 01:00:00       1     0  7.8   9.0   6.6 28.06  30.21  25.87   129
8  2016-03-05 01:10:00       1     0  7.2   9.0   4.7 24.91  29.23   9.92    91
9  2016-03-05 01:20:00       1     0  7.0   8.7   3.9 25.04  28.53  20.39    92
10 2016-03-05 01:30:00       1     0  7.2   9.1   3.7 26.04  30.39  20.75   103
11 2016-03-05 01:40:00       1     0  7.5   9.3   5.1 26.75  30.98  21.80   111
12 2016-03-05 01:50:01       1     0  7.5   8.7   4.9 26.94  28.96  22.46   114
13 2016-03-05 02:00:00       1     0  7.1   9.0   4.4 25.32  30.24  20.38    95
14 2016-03-05 02:10:00       1     0  7.5   9.0   5.0 26.47  29.35  22.85   108
15 2016-03-05 02:20:00       1     0  7.3   9.1   4.2 26.03  30.97  19.43   104
16 2016-03-05 02:30:00       1     0  6.7  10.1   3.9 24.66  30.98  20.06    88
17 2016-03-05 02:40:00       1     0  6.8   9.1   4.5 25.30  30.22  20.88    94
18 2016-03-05 02:50:00       1     0  7.2  10.1   4.2 25.95  31.17  20.74   103
19 2016-03-05 03:00:00       1     0  7.6  10.3   4.3 27.72  34.43  22.19   127
20 2016-03-05 03:10:00       1     0  8.7  12.2   5.3 31.42  35.69  25.32   189
```

I tried the following code:

```
df3 <- subset(df1, df1$timestamp > df2$timestamp[df2$State==21]-7200 & 
                   df1$timestamp < df2$timestamp[df2$State==21]+3600)
```

Basically this works for me, as the right timeframes are selected and saved in `df3`, **but**: only every fourth observation of `df1` is going into `df3`. This is what I get in the end:

```
          timestamp      PlantNo Error avws maxws minws avrot maxrot minrot avpwr
1781 2016-03-17 08:30:00       1     0  2.2   2.7   1.6 14.57  15.85  13.52     0
1785 2016-03-17 09:10:00       1     0  1.7   2.4   0.7 10.43  13.48   8.71     0
1789 2016-03-17 09:50:00       1     0  1.9   2.9   0.7 11.62  15.91   6.86     0
1793 2016-03-17 10:30:00       1     0  2.4   4.3   0.6  0.27   1.59   0.00     0
1797 2016-03-17 11:10:00       1     0  2.7   4.2   1.7 16.38  18.76  13.17     0
3006 2016-03-25 22:40:00       1     0  5.4   6.9   4.1 19.99  21.95  19.21    41
3010 2016-03-25 23:20:00       1     0  6.0   7.1   4.6 21.43  24.59  19.59    56
3014 2016-03-26 00:00:00       1     0  5.1   6.5   4.0 19.41  20.33  18.90    30
3018 2016-03-26 00:40:00       1     0  5.2   6.6   3.0  4.06  20.82   0.00     4
3022 2016-03-26 01:20:00       1     0  5.2   6.4   3.7 19.52  20.26  18.75    33
3583 2016-03-29 23:40:00       1     0  5.7   6.8   4.9 20.57  22.80  19.60    48
3587 2016-03-30 00:20:00       1     0  6.4   7.5   5.4 22.82  25.10  20.27    68
3591 2016-03-30 01:00:00       1     0  6.1   7.4   5.2 21.94  23.99  20.52    60
3595 2016-03-30 01:40:00       1     0  4.0   5.0   2.4  2.90  18.99   0.00     1
3599 2016-03-30 02:20:00       1     0  5.4   6.2   4.5 19.63  20.05  19.26    36
3812 2016-03-31 13:50:00       1     0  2.2   4.3   0.8 13.95  18.30   7.89     1
3816 2016-03-31 14:30:00       1     0  0.8   2.1   0.0  0.00   0.10   0.00     0
3820 2016-03-31 15:10:00       1     0  0.6   1.4   0.0  0.00   0.00   0.00     0
3824 2016-03-31 15:50:00       1     0  2.5   4.4   0.6 11.54  19.12   0.00     1
3828 2016-03-31 16:30:00       1     0  2.8   4.3   1.7  5.31  18.39   0.00     1
```

The leftmost columns is the number of the observation in `df1`. 
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I feel that a sample of original data with expected output would be easier to read than what you have given us.

Comment: Consider including in your post the first 10 lines of `df1` and `df2` with non-relevant columns omitted.

Comment: Does this help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your comparison `df1$timestamp>(df2$timestamp[df2$State==21]-7200)` is recycling. This is the case when `df2$State==21` returns more than one case.

Try the following, as we don't have enough data I am not sure if works for you.

```
inf=df2$timestamp[df2$State==21]-7200
sup=df2$timestamp[df2$State==21]+3600

trs=list()
for (i in 1:length(inf))trs[[i]]=df1$timestamp>inf[i] & df1$timestamp<sup[i]
selv=apply(t(do.call("rbind",trs)),1,any)
df31 <- subset(df1,selv)
```

Comment: I also think that recycling is the problem an therfore subset is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Perhaps you need `subset(df1, df1$timestamp > (df2$timestamp[df2$State==21]-7200) & df1$timestamp < (df2$timestamp[df2$State==21]+3600))`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am thinking to complicated but in my opinion subset should not work so easily.

I built an example of two data.frames with two random timestamps which are in the same range. I used an ugly nested for loop to check whether each of the timestamps in `df2` is in the range of +- 1 hour of all the timestamps with `state = 1` of `df1`. If so, `state = 1` is added to `df2`. For the desired result you can easily subset `df2`.

```
set.seed(1)
t1   <- sort(as.POSIXct(sample(1:10000000, 1000) ,origin = "2010-01-01"))
state <- sample(0:1,10000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.90,0.05) )
df1 <- data.frame(t1, state)

t2 <- sort(as.POSIXct(sample(1:10000000, 1000) ,origin = "2010-01-01" ))
df2 <- data.frame(t2, ID = 1:length(t2))

df1_h <- df1[df1$state == 1, ]

df2$state <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(df1_h)){
    if(df2$t2[i] > df1_h$t1[j] - 3600 &  df2$t2[i] < df1_h$t1[j] + 3600) df2$state[i] <- 1
  }
} 

df3 <- df2[df2$state == 1, ]
```